# Replace html tags in text with formatting in PhpWord

Tags: php, phpword

**What I have:**

- template document `template.docx` with mark inside - `${position_to_insert_text}`
- string in variable `$text_to_insert_in_template` with `<strong>` html tags inside - `My <strong>example string</strong> with html tag.`

**What I want:**

- Open template `template.docx`
- replace `${position_to_insert_text}` with `$text_to_insert_in_template`
- inserted text between `<strong>` and `</strong>` tags must be strong formatted - My **example string** with html tag.

**What I do:**

```
$text_to_insert_in_template = 'My <strong>example string</strong> with html tag.';
$template_path = 'templates/template.docx';

$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($template_path);
$templateProcessor->setValue('position_to_insert_text', $text_to_insert_in_template);
$templateProcessor->saveAs('result.docx');
```

**Result**:

Broken `result.docx` document without ability to open it. Reason - not handled html tags. If `htmlspecialchars($text_to_insert_in_template)` as result I can open `result.docx` but html tags displays as plain text.

I try to replace html tags to native word tags

```
$text_to_insert_in_template = 'My <strong>example string</strong> with html tag.';
$template_path = 'templates/template.docx';

$text_to_insert_in_template = str_replace('<strong>', "<w:b val='true'/>", $text_to_insert_in_template);
$text_to_insert_in_template = str_replace('</strong>', "<w:b val='false'/>", $text_to_insert_in_template);

$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($template_path);
$templateProcessor->setValue('position_to_insert_text', $text_to_insert_in_template);
$templateProcessor->saveAs('result.docx');
```

As result I can open `result.docx`, but text inside has no formatting and html tags too:

[image]

How can I get the result I want? - My **example string** with html tag.

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar task at hand. While searching for a solution, I found this question and want to leave our solution as example.

The general issue is, that using HTML markup as value for a macro is not (yet) supported by the template processor. Depending on your PhpWord settings, values may even be escaped using the [setValue](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html#setvalue) method. Faulty WordProcessingML may break your document.

But the template processor allows to replace `<w:p>` paragraphs ([setComplexBlock](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html#setcomplexvalue)), or `<w:r>` text runs ([setComplexValue](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html#setcomplexvalue)) that contain the macro with PhpWord elements.

And PhpWord supports basic parsing of HTML into container elements, such as table cells or text boxes. You could use this to add your HTML markup to the template. Unfortunately, this will also add the container element.

We didn't want to have this additional wrapper, and implemented a mix of both, using a wrapper container, but printing its content only.

The steps are as follows:

- Create a custom `TemplateProcessor` class that extends the generic `TemplateProcessor` of PhpWord (in our example without namespace, but you can add a suitable namespace to your liking),
- add a `setHtmlBlockValue` method, which
- instantiates a container element (`TextBox` in our example),
- utilizes the `Html` helper class to parse the HTML markup into it,
- then uses the `Container` writer to render the container content into Word2007 conform WordProcessingML,
- and last but not least replaces the entire paragraph that contains the macro with the rendered content.

```php
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\TextBox;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\XMLWriter;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor as PhpWordTemplateProcessor;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\Word2007\Element\Container;

/**
 * Custom PhpWord template processor.
 *
 * Extends the generic template processor of PhpWord by means to
 * replace a macro with HTML markup content.
 */
class TemplateProcessor extends PhpWordTemplateProcessor {

    /**
     * Replaces a macro block with the given HTML markup.
     *
     * PhpWord's variables replacing doesn't allow to use HTML markup as
     * macro replacement content.
     *
     * This method is a workaround that uses the PhpWord Html service to
     * parse Html into PhpWord elements, adds them as children to a
     * container element (TextBox), then uses the Container writer to
     * write its children elements only.
     *
     * @param string $search
     *   The macro (variable) name.
     * @param string $markup
     *   The HTML markup as a string.
     */
    public function setHtmlBlockValue($search, $markup)
    {
      // Create a dummy container element for the content.
      $wrapper = new TextBox();

      // Parse the given HTML markup and add it as child elements
      // to the container.
      Html::addHtml($wrapper, $markup);

      // Render the child elements of the container.
      $xmlWriter = new XMLWriter();
      $containerWriter = new Container($xmlWriter, $wrapper, false);
      $containerWriter->write();

      // Replace the macro parent block with the rendered contents.
      $this->replaceXmlBlock($search, $xmlWriter->getData(), 'w:p');
    }

}
```

It can be used without your manual manipulation of HTML and supports the same markup and attributes as are supported by PhpWords Html helper:

```php
$text_to_insert_in_template = 'My <strong>example string</strong> with html tag.';
$template_path = 'templates/template.docx';

$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($template_path);
$templateProcessor->setHtmlBlockValue('position_to_insert_text', $text_to_insert_in_template);
$templateProcessor->saveAs('result.docx');
```

Above code is intended as inspiration and works with sanitized HTML markup created using CKEditor. You may alter it to your needs (e.g., use table cells instead, replace text runs rather than paragraphs, ...).

Comment: Your solution is putting the html one line string into 3 lines. First line is showing `My`, second line is showing `example string` in bold, third line is showing a blank space at the start with `with html tag.' text. While it should be shown in a single line. Your solution not working for me at least. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $toOpenXML  = new HTMLtoOpenXML\Parser();
 $this->template->replaceXmlBlock('placeholder', $toOpenXML->fromHTML($html));
```